# Place the modeBar at top center using plotly.js

Tags: javascript, css, charts, plotly

I am using plotly.js to plot graph in my web app. The modeBar is placed at top right corner by default. Is there any way I can place it at the top center?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
.js-plotly-plot .plotly .modebar {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.js-plotly-plot .plotly .modebar{left: 40%}
```