# Plotly.js modebar groups icons and places it over legend

Tags: javascript, html, css, plotly, plotly.js

Here is the picture of my [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FOfv.png).  As you can see, my modebar is appearing as a grouped set of icons and is placing it over the legend.  I just copy and pasted some example code from their site using example data.  I have no other css affecting this at all.  Below is the blob of code I am using.

The similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173726/place-the-modebar-at-top-center-using-plotly-js) shows what it SHOULD look like, they are all in a single row and out of the way of the legend.

How do I make my modebar look like the one in the second link?

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>
    var trace1 = {
        x: [0, 1, 2],
        y: [10, 11, 12],
        type: 'scatter'
    };

    var trace2 = {
        x: [2, 3, 4],
        y: [100, 110, 120],
        yaxis: 'y2',
        type: 'scatter'
    };

    var trace3 = {
        x: [3, 4, 5],
        y: [1000, 1100, 1200],
        yaxis: 'y3',
        type: 'scatter'
    };

    var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

    var layout = {
        yaxis: {domain: [0, 0.33]},
        legend: {traceorder: 'reversed'},
        yaxis2: {domain: [0.33, 0.66]},
        yaxis3: {domain: [0.66, 1]}
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {displaylogo: false});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share some of the CSS that's around the plot? It's like some external CSS you have there that's making things look strange.

Comment: hmmm, apparently you are right.  the one thing i didnt try was commenting out the global css i had for the whole app.  when i did, it went to the proper position.  i suppose i should be more smart about how i do my css.  thanks for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Official "answer" for acceptance: this is usually due to external CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. @nicolaskruchten is correct, but here is an applicable solution with context.

While using the inspector, I noticed when the `svg` tag is set to `display: block` plotly's SVGs will inherit this, causing the modebar to wrap in the undesirable way:

[image]

I fixed this using a simple CSS selector, targeting the plotly class and setting the SVG display to the default `inline`. I am using plotly.js, so :

```
.js-plotly-plot svg {
  display: inline;
}
```

[image]

And *voila*, fixed.

I'm unsure why a CSS rule like this isn't already embedded within the library. One idea is that this rule may cause other layout issues depending on the plotly configuration and the order of your stylesheets.

I haven't done extensive testing, so you may need to write additional specifications or exclusions to make it work for your scenario.

An alternative to writing a rule like this would be removing the offending selector or stylesheet if possible.